# Class "hash" not found

Tags: php, database, laravel, hash, password-encryption

I am trying to hash my password before inserting it into my table using a laravel seed. Every time I run `php artisan db:seed --class=users` I get the error "Class 'hash' not found"

Here is my class:

```
 class users extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {

       User::create(array(
           'email' => '********',
           'password' => hash::make('********')
       ));
       $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
    }

 }
```

Let me know if there is any more information that you need. Thanks!

Comment: well if the class is not found - what answer did you expect from us ?

Comment: hash is a function in Laravel. What am I doing wrong that it will not load?

Comment: Try `Hash::make()`.  It's case sensitive

Comment: Thanks @user3158900. Solved that problem then more came up. Feel pretty dumb for not seeing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Hash::make()`, because the case matters. In common it's a good practise to use some coding guidelines to prevent errors of this sort.
In your case, you should write every classname in upper camelcase

```
class Users extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {

       User::create(array(
           'email' => '********',
           'password' => Hash::make('********')
       ));
       $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
    }

 }
```

Comment: To be fair user3158900 beat you to it in the comments but I have to select an answer so congrats. 

And thanks.